# Extracting node id from OpenStreetMap data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

There is a `lines` layer, and I want to extract node ids from the lines.

[image]

(the data can be downloaded from http://download.bbbike.org/osm/bbbike/Beijing/)

A possible answer is to extact vertices first (`Vector` -> `Geometry Tools` -> `Extract vertices`). However, it only generates some attributes, like `vertex_index`.

After that, I can only get its `coordinates` directly, but it is hard to retrieve the **node id itself**. (the `osm_id` in `points`).

To be specific, in the `osm` file, we can find:

```
<node id="5761117126" lat="39.9135365" lon="116.5852367" version="1"/>
<node id="5761117127" lat="39.9129296" lon="116.5880741" version="1"/>
<node id="5761117128" lat="39.9124111" lon="116.5877737" version="1"/>
<node id="5761117129" lat="39.9109294" lon="116.5873889" version="1"/>
<way id="4231222" version="1">
    <nd ref="25248785"/>
    ...
</way>
```

Now I need to get `ref`s inside `way`s.

Comment: Have you tried "join attributes by location" after extracting the nodes?

Comment: Once you load the original OSM data, the ways lose the attributes of their nodes. In QGIS and pretty much all other GIS, a line can only have one set of attributes that belongs to the whole line. Does it have to be in QGIS for you?

Comment: @Erik `join` is a feasible, but it is too time-consuming. I believe there is an elegent  and fast method.

Comment: @bugmenot123 can you recommend any tool (or libaray) to parse osm data?